# Home network issue. New connections drop not the existing

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, home-networking, ping

I have a very strange behavior that I would like to understand on my home network. 
Sometimes I lost connection to outside (request timeout on ping 8.8.8.8 for few minutes) but I don't loose connection on already made link.

For example I can have a google hangout call that will not drop but during this call I will see request timeout on 8.8.8.8 for few minutes.

When I do an `mrt` and the connection drop. It drops on nearly all points. Connection seems to drop right after the router at home.

`Packets   Pings
                     Host Loss% Snt Last Avg Best Wrst StDev
1. 192.168.0.1 13.3% 807 1.9 3.4 1.3 74.3 5.4
2. 10.**.***.1 13.3% 807 7.6 10.9 6.8 143.2 9.7
3. 213-245-254-201.rev.numericable.fr 13.4% 807 7.9 12.1 7.0 182.9 13.8
4. ip-65.net-80-236-3.static.numericable.fr 13.4% 806 28.0 27.5 21.9 235.3 11.1
5. ip-161.net-80-236-1.static.numericable.fr 13.4% 806 22.4 24.2 19.4 166.4 11.9
6. 72.14.239.145 13.4% 806 36.4 21.9 17.9 134.7 8.2
7. 72.14.233.83 13.4% 806 19.6 21.6 17.7 220.0 10.8
8. par03s15-in-f110.1e100.net 13.4% 806 21.9 24.9 20.6 166.2 10.7`

Problem disappear if I turn off and on the wifi on computers.

Comment: Any NAT SOHO router will have some finite number of connections it can maintain.  This symptom could occur if you fill the NAT table; no new connections of any type will be established until some old ones are closed (but existing communication will continue without interruption).  Without more information, that would be my first guess--especially if you have had your router for several years, and in the meantime have increased the number of networked devices in your home.

Comment: Thanks! This a new router. I don't have a lot of connections and the problem disapear if I turn off and on the computer wireless.

Comment: today big hangout call. Ping down in the middle of the call, Ping up just when I've finished the call. Maybe you're right @user4556274